# I created an app launcher in Midori. How can I delete it?

Tags: slingshot, midori

I was messing around in Midori this afternoon and I created a launcher in the Slingshot menu (see image). I didn't really want to do this; it's just a random youtube video, but now I can't figure out how to delete it. It's not listed in the Applications menu in Midori, and it's not in the Software Center. Can someone help me out?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A launcher is basically a [`.desktop` file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) which you can find in `~/.local/share/applications/`. Just delete it and the launcher is gone.

(`/usr/share/applications/` contains launchers of other applications for all users.)

Also be sure to check [~/Desktop/] - this directory is also attached to Slingshot and [`.desktop` files] will be added to the launcher, too.

Comment: I think Midori should have a better way of doing this